# Create a timestamp in objective-c like in javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios7

In objective c:

```
NSDate *past = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval oldTime = [past timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *timestamp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%0.0f", oldTime];
```

in Javascript:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

The problem is that in objective c the timestamp consists of 10 numbers, however in javascript it has 13 numbers. When I compare the difference of both is within 15 minutes I get always false.

Any ideas how to get a 13 digit timestamp in objective c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTime()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

```
Returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01:
```

`- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSince1970`

```
Returns the interval between the receiver and the first instant of 1 January 1970, GMT.
NSTimeInterval used to specify a time interval, in seconds.
```

So you need to multiply value by 1000 to convert seconds to milliseconds

```
NSDate *past = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval oldTime = [past timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *timestamp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%0.0f", oldTime * 1000];
```